# datetime (month + year) comparison with String

Tags: asp.net, datetime, asp.net-ajax, comparison

I have a TextBox and Extender AjaxCalander on it. Its working fine showing only month and year in TextBox when a date is selected. My code is below

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtCardExpiry" runat="server" Width="200px" /><span> MMYY</span>
 <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender runat="server" Format="MMyy" TargetControlID="txtCardExpiry" />
```

I want to validate if credit card is not expired

Now how I  compare `txtCardExpiry.Text` with todays month and year only

right now im using

```
 int dtNowYear = Convert.ToInt16(DateTime.Now.Year.ToString().Substring(2, 2));
            int dtNowMonth = Convert.ToInt16(DateTime.Now.Month.ToString());
            int dtExpYear = Convert.ToInt16(txtCardExpiry.Text.Substring(2, 2));
            int dtExpMonth = Convert.ToInt16(txtCardExpiry.Text.Substring(0, 2));

            if (dtNowYear == dtExpYear && dtNowMonth > dtExpMonth)
            {
                lblMessage.Attributes.Add("class", "lblMessageError");
                lblMessage.Text =
                    "Credit Card expiry month and year cannot be less than todays month and year or your Credit Card has expired";
                return false;
            }
                 else if (dtNowYear > dtExpYear) 
                {
                    if (dtNowMonth > dtExpMonth)
                    {
                        lblMessage.Attributes.Add("class", "lblMessageError");
                        lblMessage.Text =
                            "Credit Card expiry month and year cannot be less than todays month and year or your Credit Card has expired";
                        return false;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
txtCardExpiry.Text.Compare(DateTime.Now.ToString("MMyyyy"))
```

[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) 
Must say, MSDN is very helpful.

Comment: how can i only compare MMYY format with datetime.now.tostring("MMYY")

Comment: just `Datetime.now.tostring("MMyy")`, **yy** is lower case.